# Prototypes of the standard classes in a Firefox Addon

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Some context: I'm making an add-on for firefox. In firefox add-ons, js scripts can be attached to a webpage at certain events (content scripts). In those scripts I'd like to use the prototype of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Is it possible to access the prototypes of the available classes in javascript? For example: `XMLHttpRequest.toString()` returns `[object XMLHttpRequest]`, while `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` is `null`. Am I doing anything wrong, or isn't it possible to use prototypes in those scripts?

Comment: Your question is missing context. Are you using the Add-on SDK as your tags indicate? But SDK modules don't have an `XMLHttpRequest` object. Are you accessing it from a content script? You also might want to double-check your results - I cannot imagine that `XMLHttpRequest` is defined in some context but `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` is `null` (normally you get `[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must be doing something wrong. I tried with a minimal SDK-based extension, the `main.js` file being:

```js
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.google.com",
  contentScriptWhen: "end",
  contentScript: 'throw "XMLHttpRequest.prototype = " + XMLHttpRequest.prototype'
});
```

When I load google.com I see the following message in the Error Console:

> XMLHttpRequest.prototype = [object XMLHttpRequestPrototype]

So `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` is definitely not `null`.